# Criterion for $F$-related vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Here is a proposition from Lee's ISM that seems to be a problem for me.

[image]

> Why can the function $f$ be defined on any open subset of $N$? What if the composition $f\circ F$ is NOT possible? Thank you.

Comment: I believe the proposition is applicable if we require instead that $f$ is any smooth function defined on $\textbf{ALL}$ of $N$. This version is formulated in the book by Loring Tu on manifolds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, $f$ needs to be defined on an open set containing the image of $F$. Specifically, the first sentence of the proof requires that $f$ be defined on a neighborhood of $F(p)$ for all $p \in M$.

**Edit**: Moreover, in order to show that $dF_p(X_p) = Y_{F(p)}$ as derivations on (an open submanifold of) $N$, it is sufficient to check that $dF_p(X_p)f = Y_{F(p)}f$ for all functions $f$ *locally defined around $F(p)$*. This is because derivations are local operators whose values only depends on the germs of their input functions.

Comment: I'm not sure if the proposition is applicable in any situation, due to the flaw in question. But I'm fine with the step that Lee chose a smooth function defined only on a neighborhood of some point ($F(p)$) in $N$. The tangent space to an open submanifold of $N$ can be identified with the tangent space to $N$.

Comment: See my edit, I clarified why the argument still goes through